# strip all spaces from column in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a table that has

*'number'*

1234
12 34
1 2 34
1 2 3 4
ect...

so, im wondering how can i write a query that will remove all spaces?

something like

```
update `table` set number = REPLACE( ' ', '', (select 'number' from `table`));
```

is there anything that will do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Close. I believe you could write something like this:

```
update `table` set number = REPLACE( number, ' ', '');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE table SET number = REPLACE(number, ' ', '')
```