# How do I remove all spaces from a field in a mysql database in an update query?

Tags: mysql

What would be the proper syntax used to  run an update query on a table to remove all spaces from the values in a column?

I have a user table that had user names with spaces imported into it & I need to remove the spaces. i.e. "john smith sr." needs to be "johnsmithsr."

there are about 500+ occurrences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strip all spaces from column in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279072/strip-all-spaces-from-column-in-mysql)

Comment: Actually I don't need to stip out the spaces but match spaced characters with non-spaced characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE( `column` , ' ' , '' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE <table>
SET name = REPLACE(name, ' ', '') ;
```

500+ occurences is not that much so this should execute in no time

Comment: Actually I don't need to stip out the spaces but match spaced characters with non-spaced characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 update table_name set column_name = replace(column_name, ' ', '');
```

The second argument will be replaced by the third argument.

Comment: Actually I don't need to stip out the spaces but match spaced characters with non-spaced characters

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what we are looking for

```
SELECT some_columns FROM table_name WHERE REPLACE(col_name, ' ', '') LIKE 'some string';
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably your answer:

```
SELECT replace(col_name , ' ','') FROM table_name;
```